# JSON query string issue in LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have simple JSON in LoadRunner.

```
{
    "type": "valid",
    "price": "low",
    "place": "newyork",
    "post": "valid"
}
```

I want to set the name of `place` from  `"newyork"` to `"california"`. I have tried:

```
lr_json_set_values("JsonObject=json_obj",
"Value=california",
"QueryString=$.place",
"SelectAll=Yes",
LAST);
```

Please help me in resolving it.

Comment: Why did you tag "loadrunner"?

Comment: @SaravananSachi This is a loadrunner question (`lr_json_set_values`)

Comment: @KobyDouek Sorry, not aware of it. Little confused as it is not mentioned in the question but just tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
lr_json_set_values( "JsonObject=json_obj",
                    "Value=\"\california\"",
                    "QueryString=$.place",
                    LAST);
```